# Supporting both landscape orientations in Honeycomb

Tags: android, screen, orientation, android-3.0-honeycomb, screen-orientation

Is it possible to support both landscape orientations in Honeycomb? My application is set to landscape orientation only, but it doesn't change if you flip the device 180 degrees.

Comment: Check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Comment: Awesome answer to a 2-year old question that was already answered...

Comment: It's not an answer... It's a link for future visitors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. Set the `android:screenOrientation` attribute in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to `sensorLandscape`.

You can read the [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Comment: How can I do this in Android 2.2?